# Doesn't get Access_accept packet from freeradius server

Tags: debugging, client-server, client-side, packet, freeradius

**1.From client**:

```
root@amsys-LIFEBOOK-AH502:/home/amsys# radtest -t chap usr password 127.0.0.1 0 testing123
```

This is how,the way i sended a packet access-request packet from the client (here,loop back only).
**2.From server**.
    the server responds to client as shown as below:

```
Ready to process requests.
Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 as server default from unknown client 127.0.0.1 port 34962 proto udp
```

**3.server to client**

```
Sending Access-Request of id 67 from 0.0.0.0 port 47852 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
User-Name = 'usr'
User-Password = 'password'
NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
NAS-Port = 0
Message-Authenticator = 0x00
radclient: no response from server for ID 67 socket 3
```

if anybody would aware about this thing,please give your prompt response and pleased me.thanking you.!